# How to split a feature in pandas

Tags: pandas, machine-learning, deep-learning, recommendation-engine

This is the first 5 examples of the training set i'm working on. I'm supposed to predict the rating given by that user to other comedy in the test set.

So this is how the test set looks, but without the ratings:

So i have a few questions:

1.What would be the best way to seperate the joke identifier into Comedian and Location. For example, Klint De Drunk is a comedian, Enugu 1 is a location

2. What would be the best approach to get the best prediction accuracy deep learning wise.

Thank you

```
     Viewers_ID    Joke_identifier              Response_ID         Rating
       0    A1  Klint De Drunk Enugu 1  A1_Klint De Drunk Enugu 1   0.11
       1    A1  Klint De Drunk Enugu 2  A1_Klint De Drunk Enugu 2   -4.64
       2    A1  Klint De Drunk PH 1     A1_Klint De Drunk PH 1      -3.39
       3    A1  Klint De Drunk PH 2     A1_Klint De Drunk PH 2      0.44
       4    A1  Klint De Drunk Lagos 1  A1_Klint De Drunk Lagos 1   -4.83
       5    A1  Klint De Drunk Lagos 2  A1_Klint De Drunk Lagos 2   -4.52
```

Comment: I suggest you make two seperate questions of this. #2. is too broad as described right now.

Comment: Question has nothing to do with `tensorflow` - kindly do not spam the tag (removed).

Answer (score 1):

for point 1:

use:

```
df['Joke_identifier_new'] = df['Joke_identifier'].str.rsplit(n=2).str[0]
df['location'] = df['Joke_identifier'].str.rsplit(n=2).str[1:].str.join(' ')
print(df)
```

However, you should create a new column for the split, do not assign it back as the second code wouldnot yeild desired results. You can then drop the original columns if required.

Comment: Thank you so much. This throw back the joke identifier as comedian. But i want joke identifier split into comedian and location.

Comment: the second line of the code splits  the location in a column called location. is it not working? this gives me `Klint De Drunk`  under `Joke_identifier_new` column and `Enugu 1` in `location` column